# Why the message "No databases are selected to publish" is shown when trying to publish a web?

Tags: c#, database, model-view-controller, publish, webdeploy

I created an application on my local machine using

1) MVC
2) Entity Framework
3) LocalDB

When I go through the publishing wizard it tells me that "No databases are selected to publish"

Why is it not detecting I have a database to publish, even though I entered the connection string manually(from web.config)?

I followed the guide in the link: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465337(v=vs.110).aspx in "Configuring Databases in the Settings Tab" section.

Still, when I enter the connection string of the DB in the destination remote connection combobox under "Databases" title  and try to publish- The mentioned message is displayed.

Do you have any idea what the problem is?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is an MDF file in App_Data (couldn't tell exactly from the question) make sure:

- your connection string includes "AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\XXX.mdf"
- your MDF file is part of your solution under App_Data
- the .mdf file is configured as "Content" for the Build Action.
- Also In your publish profile, ensure that "Exclude files from the App_Data folder" is not checked under File Publish Options.

This all worked for me using EF6 code first. You should not need to specify a connection string in the publish page unless you want to change it from your web.config.